# Django field Error

Tags: python, django

I am a Django beginner working on Django v1.9 and trying to learn and replicate DjangoGirl tutorial. I have stuck at "Dynamic data in templates" and "Django templates".

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your views here.



def post_list(request):

    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts':posts})
```

the given "view.py" showing error

```
Exception Value:    
Cannot resolve keyword 'published_date' into the field. Choices are: author, author_id, creat_date, id, publish_Data, text, title
```

I have tried each and everything possible but it's not working... kindly help.

Comment: You have called your field the wrong thing in the model: you named it `publish_Data`. So you need to use the same name in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post
from django.utils import timezone

def post_list(request):

    posts = Post.objects.filter(publish_Data__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('publish_Data')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts':posts})
```